# Lock-screen information lost calls etc

Tags: security, lock-screens, customization

At my company we use Sophos MDM solution, witch forces all user to set a PIN on their lock screen. I use a Samsung S3 (android 4.1.2) and the lock screen is only a huge numeric key pad. The oterones using iPhone can have their phone to show lost cals, incoming mail, sms etc as a banner on the lock screen. 
Is it possible to have the same features on my Samsung device? Is it possible to customize the lock screen?
Have tried to download some apps, like GO Locker, but they appear before or after my lock screen so it doesn’t work as intended

Answer (score 0):

[Dashclock widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock) is an amazing app to let you view missed calls or notifications right from your lock screen for Android 4.2 and up. Since you're still on Android 4.1.2, install [WidgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) lock screen and use it.